# Proof of finding duplicate element(s) in an array in O(1) space

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given that the size of the array is n+2, and the input elements are restricted to the range (1, n), I came across a method that uses negation (Method 5, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-two-repeating-elements-in-a-given-array/) to solve the problem of finding duplicates using O(1) space. However, I'm not entirely convinced why this works, can someone help with a proof?

Comment: Method 5 works for 1 based arrays.  Let's say the array was A = {2. 3. 1. 3} You read the first value (2) and swap the sign of A[2] so that the array is now {2. -3. 1. 3}  You read the next value (3) and swap the sign of A[3] so that the array is now {2. -3. -1. 3}  You read the next value (1) and swap the sign of A[1] so that the array is now {-2. -3. -1. 3}  You read the next value (3) and swap the sign of A[3] so that the array is now {-2. -3. +1. 3}  And you are done with Step 1. Now look at the sign of the first n values: if negative only changed once, if positive then changed twice (dup)

Comment: Please, don't put important information into off-site links, instead [edit] your question to include the relevant information in the question itself. Your question should be fully self-contained and answerable without following any links. Please, make sure to not violate any copyrights when doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see that this algorithm works, it might help to first solve it with *extra* space.

### Counting occurrences

Create an array called `count` with indexes 1 through n, initialised to all zeroes. This will keep track of how often you encounter a certain value in the input array. Then check which counts are greater than 1. So the algorithm (pseudo code) is quite straightforward:

```py
count := array(n) 
# initialise counts:
for i := 1 to n: 
    count[i] = 0
# start counting:
for value in A:
    count[value] := count[value] + 1
# extract non-uniques
duplicates := array()
for i := 1 to n:
    if count[i] > 1:
        duplicates.append(i)
return duplicates
```

### Flagging occurrences

We can observe that we could already detect the duplicate when we increased a certain count from 1 to 2. So we don't really need to *store* a count of 2. We could just leave the count at 1 and add the value to the output. The first time we encounter a value, the corresponding 0 will become 1, and the next time we will see there is already a 1 and conclude that we have a duplicate (and leave the 1 as-is). So this way we would only need to store two kinds of values (0 or 1). We would use a more appropriate name for this auxiliary array: instead of `count` it could be named `found`.

```py
found := array(n)
# initialise:
for i := 1 to n: 
    found[i] := 0
# loop and collect duplicates:
duplicates := array()
for value in A:
    if found[value] == 0:
        found[value] := 1
    else:  # already encountered this value before
        duplicates.append(value)
    
return duplicates
```

### Packing data together

Storing just a 0 or 1 is actually nothing more than storing one bit. To get rid of the auxiliary space, we can argue that we surely have an unused bit available in each value of the input array: it was given that the input values are all in the range 1..n, so they are positive, and thus the sign bit is not used. We could "hide" our bit information in there!

For this to work, we must make sure the use of that bit does not interfere with the storage of the input values.

So, when we read a value from the input array, we must be sure to ignore that sign bit (by taking the absolute value). And when we want to read/write the extra bit, we should be sure not to interfere with the original (positive) input value. The bit and the value should coexist together without influencing each other. You could see it as a tuple with 2 data: a bit and a number between 1..n. They are unrelated.

It is essentially no different from the algorithm above (with `found`). The only difference is that two (unrelated) data are packed together into one value.

I hope that when you look at it that way, the algorithm becomes clear.

### Remark

One criticism to this algorithm is that it really *does* use extra space. Imagine your input consists of unsigned bytes, and *n* is 255, then really there is no space left for an extra bit.